# Typescript: Use @types for jsrsasign without import

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-extension, import, module, typescript-typings

I'm developing a typescript application (chrome extension) and want to use @types for a downloaded library jsrsasign-all-min.js from https://github.com/kjur/jsrsasign. Therefore I've installed:

`npm install --save @types/jsrsasign`.

Now the only way to get it working in .ts file is:

```
(window as any).KJUR.jws.JWS.readSafeJSONString((window as any).b64utoutf8(token))
```

IDE allows me to do imports:

```
import { b64utoutf8, KJUR } from "jsrsasign";
KJUR.jws.JWS.readSafeJSONString(b64utoutf8(token))
```

but this will throw a runtime error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

I also can do this without import:

```
jsrsasign.KJUR.jws.JWS.readSafeJSONString(jsrsasign.b64utoutf8(token))
```

but this will also result in runtime error:

> Error handling response: ReferenceError: jsrsasign is not defined

**Question**: is there a way to get it working in .ts files with type control?

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "extension",
    "target": "es6",
    "removeComments": true,
  },
  "include": [
    "**.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you managed to solve this issue? I have the same problem